# Ember calling delete action for object in each loop behaves strangely

Tags: ember.js

In ember calling an action to delete from model in a #each always deletes the last object.

```
{{#each itm in content}}
  <li>
      {{itm.firstName}} {{itm.lastName}} 
      <button {{action delete itm}}>delete</button>
  </li>
{{/each}} 


App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
actions:{
    delete: function(itm){
        alert("deleting " + itm.firstName + " " + itm.lastName)
        this.content.popObject(itm);
    }
}
});
```

it seems like when I delete the object ember gets lost in his action references and always deletes the last item!

but the alert box gives me the right data.

here is a fiddle cause I find this hard to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/ap4qD/

Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.content.removeObject(itm);` Worked in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ap4qD/3/) you provided.

Comment: thanks @claptimes! do you happen to know why its acting weird with `popObject`? they both achieve the same goal in the end! must be some more wiring done in `removeObject` then?

Comment: They are different. Take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/mutable_array.js#L188) `popObject` removes the last element of the array.

Comment: Here's the [docs](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/mutable_array.js#L188) for removeObject. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! I should have checked this! this was so stupid/lazy of me! thanks again!